# (Unity) How do I add a force to a specific point on an object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

For a game i've been making in Unity, I need to apply two forces to an object: Firstly, I need a force that pushes the object forward, I use this code for doing so:

```
    void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(Input.GetKey("a"))
    {
        Thruster.AddRelativeForce(0, -Thrustforce * Time.deltaTime, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey("z"))
    {
        Thruster.AddRelativeForce(0, Thrustforce * Time.deltaTime, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
}
```

Now I also want to add a sideways force, but that needs to be at a very specific place to get the vehicle feeling just the way I want it. I haven't been able to find anything on the internet about this. So the question is: how would I apply this sideways force in a specific place on the object?

I am still a beginner when it comes to Unity and coding, so please do explain what steps you would take.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: how about [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking on the internet before asking the question would give you this result:

[AddForceAtPosition()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html)

Comment: Yeah i found that, but i didn't really understand how to use it. That's why I asked it here. Anyways, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? You simply specify the force vector using the first parameter and the position where the force is applied using the second one.

Comment: ... and I'd suggest using `ForceMode.Force` or `ForceMoce.Acceleration` most of the time if there isn't any special case which requires a instantaneous `VelocityChange`.